# Meteor.js on Samsung ARMv71 Chromebook Series 3?

Tags: arm, meteor, google-chrome-os

While there's no official support for Meteor.js on ARM architectures, I'm disappointed that my (new and lovely) Chromebook can't run Meteor within Unity (ubuntu 12.04 LTS) chroot via crouton - http://goo.gl/ilSFSz

I've tried the suggestions for the Raspberry Pi ARM here - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/442 - and for the most part, I'm using node v0.8.24 outlined here - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/scripts/generate-dev-bundle.sh - and the latest error I received was a Assertion Error: Unsupported architecture when building mongodb here, line 298 in ../mongo/src/third_party/v8/SConscript:

```
processor = env[PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE]
```

And ARMv71 isn't listed, so I wondered if anyone has found a way to get Meteor.js to run natively on their armv71 chromebook? I would prefer not to use cloud9 or nitrous.io, or amazon ec2 to do meteor development on the Chromebook. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the most part, the work-around I've been using for Meteor is nitrous.io :) Eventually, I'll check back if anyone has found support for the arm7 chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you know sh or bash you could try modifying the meteor [install script](https://install.meteor.com) for the ARM architecture.

Comment: Try to give suggestions as comments.

Answer (score 0):

As I know from other users, our meteor universal arm fork should work for you.

https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

Cheers
Tom