# Error installing Meteor on linux x86_64 chrome os

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-os

I am trying to install Meteor on the HP14 Chromebook.  It is a linx x86_64 chrome os system.

Each time I try to install it I run into errors.

The first time I tried to install it the installer just downloaded the Meteor preengine but never downloaded the tarball or installed the actual meteor application structure.

So, I decided to try as sudo.

`sudo curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`

This definitely installed it because you can see it when ls

`chronos@localhost ~/projects $ chronos@localhost ~/projects $ ls /home/chronos/user/.meteor/
bash: chronos@localhost: command not found`

Now when I try to run meteor --version or meteor create myapp without sudo I get the following error.

````
chronos@localhost ~/projects $ meteor create myapp
'/home/chronos/user/.meteor' exists, but '/home/chronos/user/.meteor/meteor' is not executable.

Remove it and try again.
````

When I try to run sudo meteor --version or sudo meteor create myapp I get this error.

`chronos@localhost ~/projects $ sudo meteor create myapp
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/.meteor-install-tmp’: Read-only file system`

Any ideas?  Thinking I have to make that partition writeable.  I made partition 4 writeable.

Comment: Maybe you can fix this just by making '/home/chronos/user/.meteor/meteor' executable (chmod +x)

Comment: The chromebook is not an x86 processor like a PC.   Therefore you need to compile from source with an appropriate compiler.  But even then there are reports of trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385767/meteor-js-on-samsung-armv71-chromebook-series-3

Comment: You also might consider a cloud development environment like nitrous.io or c9.io so you can edit with your web browser and run on  a VPS.

Comment: @antlsoft I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work.  I suspect that isn't working more so because I might need to do this to the root sudo /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification

Comment: @Paul it is a celeron 2955u processor and not ARM I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your chrome book into dev mode.

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices

Boot into dev mode.

ctrl-alt t to crosh

`shell
sudo su -
cd /usr/share/vboot/bin/
./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 4
reboot`

After rebooting

`sudo su -
mount -o remount,rw /
mount -o remount,exec /mnt/stateful_partition`

Write yourself a read/write script

`sudo vim /sbin/rw`

```
 #!/bin/bash
  echo "Making FS Read/Write"
  sudo mount -o remount,rw /
  sudo mount -o remount,exec /mnt/stateful_partition
  sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user
  echo "You should now have full Read/Write access"
  exit
```

Change permissions on script

`sudo chmod a+x /sbin/rw`

Run to set read/write root

`sudo rw`

Install Meteor as indicated on www.meteor.com via curl and meteor create works!

Alternatively you can edit the chomeos_startup though that might not be the best idea.  It is probably best to have read/write on demand as illustrated above.

`cd /sbin sudo 
sudo vim chromeos_startup`

Go to lines 51 and 58 and remove the noexec options from the mount command.

Down at the bottom of the script, above the note about ureadahead and below the if statement, add in:

```
mount -o remount,exec /mnt/stateful_partition 
#uncomment this to mount root r/w on boot 
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Again, editing chromeos_startup probably isn't the best idea unless you are so lazy you can't type sudo rw.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy to fix!!

Just run this (or put it in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to make it permanent):

```
sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user
```

Based on your question (you are using sudo) I assume you already have Dev Mode enabled, which is required for the above `sudo` command to work.

ChromeOS mounts the home folder using the `noexec` option by default, and this command remounts it with `exec` instead. And boom, Meteor will work just fine after that (and so will a bunch of other programs running out of your home folder).

Original tip: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/928